# How do I change the number of indent guide lines in Sublime Text 2?

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext

The current indent guide lines show only on intervals of 12 spaces.
I want them to show on intervals of 4 spaces, so they match my tab width exactly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use a monospaced font.  Either, comment out the `font_face` setting in your *Settings - User* file or change it to a monospaced font available in your os.

Comment: Commenting it out will show guide lines every 2 spaces.. Any clue on how I can get it to show every 4 spaces? I'd also like to use my regular, non-monospaced font, if that's at all possible, by any other means.

Comment: Actually, commenting it out will show guide lines equal to the tab width of the current document. (I just had a document with tab width set to 2). Any clue on how to get the effect with a non-monospaced font?

Comment: I doubt it is possible. A unit of tab spacing is derived from the width of one character.  So if your tab width is 4, then Sublime will move the spacing over 4 character widths.  If the characters are not uniform, then the tab spacing would not match up with your actual text.

Comment: Right.  The space characters aren't matching up with your smaller width characters. So it looks like the tab is going 12 characters, but it is actually that your "i"s and "l"s are not able stretch your code to the four space characters.

Comment: Hm, not sure I understand you.. If it uses the space character width (which is uniform) to make the guide lines, shouldn't it draw guide lines every 4 spaces, regardless of the other characters?
If the other characters match up or not with the guide lines is another case. Basically, [when using a normal font](http://cl.ly/image/332M0C100v1b) the gray vertical guide lines should be drawn every 4th space, like [when I use a monospaced font](http://cl.ly/image/1A320P1d1914).

Comment: I was wrong in assuming that it uses the space as it's guide as a tab unit.  I'm not sure what it uses.  However, if you use tabs for indentation instead of spaces, you get proper looking guide lines.

Comment: Yeah, that's true. I need to use spaces for indentation though, and a non-monospaced font. =/ Whenever I'm unsure about indentation now, I just switch to a monospaced font, or Convert Indentation to Tabs. Hopefully, having an indent interval of 4 spaces (instead of 2) will make me less unsure about the correctness of the indentation. Thus, the indent guide lines won't matter as much. I will accept your answer, even though it doesn't solve the problem exactly, but since it solves it sufficiently for me, and since you've been very helpful. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue and found out that the "Tab Width" for my document (2) differed from the setting "tab_size" (4)

What I had to do was to change "Tab Width" in:
**View / Indentation / Tab Width**